# Calculation of a tensor components

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

If a (1,2)-tensor T is given by $T=\sum_{i,j,l=1}^{4}t_{ij}^l\frac{\partial}{\partial x_l}\otimes dx_i\otimes dx_j$, how do we calculate $Tx_{1}$? Is this true: $Tx_1 = t_{11}^1+t_{12}^1+t_{21}^1 +t_{22}^1$?

Comment: $T$ needs to eat three arguments: 1 covector and two vectors

Answer (score 0):

If we have a manifold $M$, we can define a tensor to the point $m$ as a multi-linear map $T_m:(T_mM)^p\times (T^*_mM)^q\to\mathbb{R}$. In your example $p=2,q=1$, so that tensor acts on elements of the tangent space and cotangent space in a point $m\in M$. It will take two vectors and one co-vector.

Remember that a tensor evaluated on a point $p\in M$ (choosing a local chart, it has coordinates $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$) has as arguments vectors and co-vectors and as result we get a number. $Tx_1$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: But I have to calculate $(\nabla_X K)_Z$. Is this mean $\nabla_X KZ - K\nabla_X  Z$? So I have K (*).

Comment: Sorry, here $K = T$.

Comment: What $Z$ and $X$ are? Could you provide other details? It seems a Lie derivative...is it possible?

Comment: Z and X are basis elements of a space that we calculate on. No, I do not think it is a Lie derivative.

Comment: I was thinking to write T as $T=t^1_{11}e_1 + t^2_{11}e_2+ t^1_{12}e_1+...$ and to find $\frac{\partial t^1_{11}}{\partial e_1}$ and so on. That is how I would get $\nabla_{e_{1}}T$. Next, I would differentiate the obtained expression wrt $e_2$. I don't know if I am right.